# Show current date in yy/MM/dd format

Tags: sitecore-forms

I need Sitecore forms to render the current date always in `yy/MM/dd` format. However, the default field format is different. Any way of achieving this in Sitecore forms?

Comment: have a look on this conversation - https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/10/t/10466

Comment: @GauravAgarwal yes i hve gone through it and according to them custom field needs to be created but it also have error in IE. I am looking for some other approach